# Why do we connect the File owner View Outlet with the view object in nib file

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am currently trying to grasp various ios development concepts. I wanted to know what purpose does dragging and attaching the `view` outlet (from the file owner in Connection Inspector) to the view object serve ? Currently I just think that the way it is done but I would like to know why and what purpose it serves ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It lets a view controller created in code reference a view inside the nib.

When you load a nib (`-[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:]`), you pass an object in the `owner` parameter. This object becomes the "File's Owner" and has its outlets hooked up as specified in the nib.

The typical UIViewController initializer, `-[UIViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]`, calls the above method with itself as the owner. That's how it gets a reference to the view from nibland.